# "The selection cannot be run on any server" error after updating Eclipse & PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, localhost, eclipse-pdt

I recently updated both my Eclipse IDE & PHP version on my laptop and I am now receiving an error whenever attempting to test/run locally. Previously I had been running PHP version 7.2 and **upgraded to 7.4.** I had also **upgraded to Eclipse 2020-3** from 2018-09 via the application itself after adding the Eclipse.org directory for 2020-03 to the list of locations for the application to hunt for updates.

Attempts were also made to resolve the issue by clearing out metadata files and a **clean install of Eclipse** after deleting all folders I could find within my Windows user folders and Program Files location.

The "**The selection cannot be run on any server**" error occurs any time I attempt to **Run As < Run on Server**. When attempting to **configure a server indirectly and adding/configuring the current project I receive a message stating "The server does not support version 7.4 of the PHP Project specification."**

I attempted to check the Project < Properties < Project Facets to see if the incorrect PHP version is selected, but it is already displaying PHP Facet 7.4.

I have an older version of PHP and Eclipse running on my desktop and I attempted to compare the two for a driver of the issue, but could not come to a conclusion beyond the update. I have seen similar issues reported on Youtube, Stackoverflow, Eclipse.org, and Reddit; but none have disclosed anything that I have been able to flag and successfully implement as a fix.

I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: I do not have direct experience with either product your using, but, based on your question, I do see one thing which may point you in the right direction. You said that you updated to PHP 7.4. You also said that the specific error message you are receiving is "The server does not support version 7.4 of the PHP Project specification". This error, to me, would indicate that you will not be able to run in this configuration.. Have you tried reverting back to PHP 7.2? Hope that helps some...